# VBA Code to open 100+ csv files, extract the date from the filename, an the use that date to append a new field to the file

Tags: vba, excel, loops, csv

Im about to try and start to solve this for myself but I would like to ask the community if they have done anything like this before?

I have 100+ csv files that I need to open, extract the date from the filename, add the extracted date to the file as a new column. I need to loop through potentially 100s of csv files and therefore d not want to do it manually

I have come up with the following code below.. it works perfect for the first file but then the second file has the first files data added to it and then the 3rd file has both the 1st and 2nd files data in it. Its like my variables or arrays are not being emptied before being used again.. Also the date grabber is not working for the 2nd and 3rd files. So it works perfectly for the first file but my loops and array variables are not combining well in the 2nd and 3rd iterations of the loop. Please help :(

```
Sub DirLoop()

' Create a string to hold the file folder

' Create variables for holding data

Dim MyFile As String
Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
Dim Folder As String

' Open the file dialog
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Show

' Set the Folder variable with the path string

Folder = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

' Make a directory request

MyFile = Dir(Folder & "\" & "*.csv")

' Start the loop which will continue until there are no more files found

Do While MyFile <> ""

' Extract the date from the filename

    Dim newDate As String
    Dim month As String
    Dim day As String
    Dim year As String

' Extract the date pieces from the filename
    day = Mid(MyFile, 7, 2)
    month = Mid(MyFile, 5, 2)
    year = Mid(MyFile, 1, 4)
    newDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year

' Open the file

    Dim Line_FromFile As String
    Dim NextFile As String
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim arBuffer() As String
    Dim FF1 As Integer

    NextFile = Folder & "\" & MyFile

    MsgBox NextFile

' Read file
    FF1 = FreeFile
    Open NextFile For Input As #FF1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #FF1, Line_FromFile
        num = num + 1
        ReDim Preserve arBuffer(num)
        ' Store in array
        arBuffer(num) = Line_FromFile & "," & newDate
    Loop

    Close #FF1

' Write File
    FF1 = FreeFile
    Open NextFile For Output As #FF1

    For i = 1 To num
        Print #FF1, arBuffer(i)
    Next i

    Close #FF1

' MyFile = Dir() will contiune to grab the next csv file
    MyFile = Dir()

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're not a code writing service. Rather than being *about to start to solve this for yourself*, you should go ahead and do so. If you run into difficulties along the way, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the code to demonstrate what you've done so far, and ask a *specific question* related to that code, and we can try and help. Good luck.

Comment: Typically you're going to find it much easier to write out the modified files into a subfolder.  Then if you make a mistake your original files will still be available and you will be able to compare "before" and "after".  I think in this case Dir() is getting confused because you're adding new files while at the same time looping through the existing ones.  If you really want to use the same folder for the new files then get all of the input filenames into an array before you start any processing.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for your post. It works fine for the first file but the 2nd and 3rd files do not contain the newly created date field. Any ideas on why this would be? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()

    Dim Folder As String, allFiles As Collection, f
    Dim sDate As String, fso, arrLines, l

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    Folder = PickAFolder()
    Set allFiles = GetFiles(Folder, "*.csv")

    For Each f In allFiles

        sDate = Mid(f, 7, 2) & "/" & Mid(f, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(f, 1, 4)

        arrLines = Split(fso.opentextfile(Folder & "\" & f).readall(), vbCrLf)

        With fso.opentextfile(Folder & "\" & f, 2)
            For Each l In arrLines
                If Len(l) > 0 Then .writeline l & "," & sDate
            Next l
            .Close
        End With

    Next f

End Sub

Function PickAFolder() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        PickAFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function

Function GetFiles(path As String, Optional pattern As String = "") As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    f = Dir(path & pattern)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        rv.Add f
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    Set GetFiles = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry Tim correction... it works for the first file but each subsequent file it adds the date to 1 cell only.. The cell its selecting is the next available row in the 2nd column.. no idea why this is happening. Any help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Hi Tim, It must be something to do with the formatting of the csv files.. if I remove all columns except 2 and all rows except 4 rows it works... now not all columns have data in the cells so maybe its something to do with that?

Comment: So I don't think the split function is working the way we think it should work.. is there another way to read the lines into the array without using the readall() with delimiter? ta

Comment: The way you were reading the file in your original code should work fine.  My example was assuming the line separator was CR+LF: it's possible that's not the case.  Also seems like there may be some issue(s) with your input files though, since the first one is OK but following ones have issues - are you able to share some of them?

Comment: Hi Tim, I've worked it out.. I changed the spit function to look at Chr(10) and that seems to work. for some of the files this created blank lines but I then just sorted and then deleted the blank rows once I ran the command line script to combine all the files. I also moved the date to the start of the writeline function for ease of use. Thanks for all your help with this greatly appreciated!